# How to use aria2 in my python GUI program?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, download, aria2

I am using the **aria2c** downloader ( https://aria2.github.io/ ) in my **python** script. The **aria2c** is a **command-line tool** to batch download some stuff.

```
import os
#...
os.system("aria2c " + url)
```

The output of **aria2c** is displayed in the same console with the **downloaded percentage** and **download speed** etc.

Now, I want to convert my python program to a **GUI**. The **GUI** must display information of the **download speed and percentage**, which must be **graphical labels** in **Tkinter GUI**.

Is there any way to use **aria2c** and achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `aria2p` solves your problem.
Here's the [link](https://pypi.org/project/aria2p/).

Comment: I tried this but the library does not even download simple links without error... Will try again and let you know! Who knows they fixed the bugs...

Comment: Well if you think this library is not useful then others would thank you to fork it and update it. And yes they may have fixed the bugs since you said they are major problems

Comment: Hey, aria2p's author here. Don't hesitate to report bugs on the issue tracker: https://github.com/pawamoy/aria2p/issues. Also please note that aria2p is just a frontend/client for aria2c, which must run as a daemon with RPC enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Python default library's [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module allows you to call and interact with other programs. That will certainly suit your problem very well.

Comment: So how do I interact?

Comment: Please read the provided documentation or/and a tutorial if you have a hard time getting started (_e.g._ https://pymotw.com/3/subprocess/)

Comment: Actually I am also using subprocess in my program. I don't have any problem understanding the documentation. My question is related to how to get the required output of aria2 into a GUI. Actually, the output of aria2 in the console changes every second. Let's just say I want to make it look like a GUI download manager.

Comment: “Console changes” are still writes to `stdout` (or `stderr`, whatever), so there is not much difference with processing “regular” outputs.

Comment: Did you find some way to achieve this, if , can you please mentioned it here.